# How can I get class dependencies programmatically and their respective file locations?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I need to get some sort of a dependency graph between classes of a given project i.e. all the classes which that specific class uses. I want to know which classes a given class is using so that I can later find their file path within a project. Consider the following simple example:

```cs
public class Dog: Animal, IBark
{
    public void Bark()
    {
        // Code to bark.
    }

    public void Fight(Cat cat)
    {
        // Code to fight cat.
    }
}
```

For this specific example, I would like to know which classes the `Dog` class uses. So I would like to programmatically get access to an object that has those dependencies. In this situation, that object would contain the `IBark`, `Animal` and `Cat` classes/interfaces and possibly their respective file paths.

Is this possible in C#? I have tried looking into the Roslyn API and although I can parse the document and traverse it to find the nodes I have not found a way to get metadata related to those nodes that could possibly give me what I am looking for (e.g. file paths). This got me wondering if there is not a better approach to this problem out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `Roslyn` apis. The algorithm is the following:

1. Load solution (.sln)
2. Iterate through projects (.csproj)
3. Iterate through documents (.cs) within the project
4. Load `semantic model` for the document
5. Get `SyntaxTree` and traverse all `SyntaxNode`
6. Detect each `SyntaxNode` concrete type. If detected syntax is a class definition (let's say Dog) - continue to traverse considering that further detected class or interface depend on Dog

Sample code below. Also I committed this in [github](https://github.com/amikulich/ArchitectureGuards). You will be interested in [sample unit tests](https://github.com/amikulich/ArchitectureGuards/tree/master/ArchitectureGuards/ArchitectureGuards.Tests/DependencyGraph) and [sample solution based on your example](https://github.com/amikulich/ArchitectureGuards/tree/master/Samples/DependencyGraph/SampleProject1ForDependencyGraph). I did an assumption that single file contains only one class definition, however I think that this should be enough for you to start.

```
        var dependencies = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); 
        //key - class name, value - list of dependent class names

        var project = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.First();

        foreach (var document in project.Documents)
        {
            var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
            KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>? keyValue = null;

            foreach (var item in semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes())
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration:
                    case InterfaceDeclarationSyntax interfaceDeclaration:
                        if (!keyValue.HasValue)
                        {
                            keyValue = new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(item).Name, new List<string>());
                        }
                        break;
                    case SimpleBaseTypeSyntax simpleBaseTypeSyntax:
                        keyValue?.Value.Add(simpleBaseTypeSyntax.Type.ToString());
                        break;
                    case ParameterSyntax parameterSyntax:
                        keyValue?.Value.Add(parameterSyntax.Type.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (keyValue.HasValue)
            {
                dependencies.Add(keyValue.Value.Key, keyValue.Value.Value);
            }
        }
```

For the code above workspace is loaded in the following way:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFilePath);
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a good starting point. I ended up doing something similar but still learned some things from your answer.