# Monitor classes added/removed in Visual Studio extension

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I want to write an extension for Visual Studio 2019 that is somewhat similar to the built-in Class View. So I want a Tool Window that shows a list (tree) of classes that are present under current solution.

I can think of two things:

1. I need to scan projects and find classes
2. Every time a source file gets edited, I need to know about this immediately to add a newly written class or to remove existing.

Please point me the direction to search in. I guess I should use .NET Compiler Platform SDK, but cannot figure out how. There seems to be no interfaces with events or such.

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56184238/16363677) give you some references? Also, this answers: [hashs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014886/16363677), [MD5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640068/16363677)  may be helpful.

Comment: Not quite. That thread is about scanning every project and file in a solution, which I can use for initial building of the list. But then, it would be ridiculous to repeat all that steps when the user edits the code even a bit.

Comment: Is there a high-level Roslyn API like 'ClassAdded' event? Or should I watch the project files manually and rescan them on change?

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to the RunningDocTableEvents. This deals with all open files (the only ones which should change). There is a BeforeSave and an AfterSave event you can listen for and then rescan the appropriate file.

```
 var runningDocumentTable = (IVsRunningDocumentTable)GetService(typeof(SVsRunningDocumentTable));

 runningDocumentTable.AdviseRunningDocTableEvents(_viewModel, out _viewCookie);
```

Your _viewModel must implement the IVsRunningDocTableEvents3 interface (any events not needed should just return S_OK.
For example:

```
  #region IVsRunningDocTableEvents3 Members

  public int OnAfterAttributeChange(uint docCookie, uint grfAttribs)
    {
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

  ...  

    public int OnAfterSave(uint docCookie)
    {
        // do something here
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }
```